# How to use Get-ChildItem with specified path, file name, or both too long?

Tags: powershell

I have created one-line script for removing `.lnk` files:

```
get-childitem e:\ -include *MozillaFirefox.lnk*  -recurse -force | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

But it end up with below error:

> ```
> get-childitem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, 
> and the directory name must be less than 248 characters
> ```

Please help to resolve this issue

Comment: This isn't an error in your script, its an issue with Windows. Depending on how items are created, they can have file paths longer than 248 characters, but these aren't supported natively by the OS. Have a read of this article which might help: https://win32.io/posts/Long-Path-Support-In-Powershell

Comment: is it possible to do same changes in windows 2012r2 and windows 2016 servers?

Comment: @JatinFirme It works on all OS that are based on NT 10.0. So, Windows 10, Windows Server 2016 and 2019. You might have to [enable it](https://superuser.com/a/1119980/1077440) though. If you want to handle long file paths/names on older OS, use the built-in `robocopy` tool. It can handle them.